# How is a const array able to have only characters in each element but a char* array is able to point to strings in each element?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

```
char characters[] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};


char* characters[] = {"h","e","l","l","o"};
```

How is the latter able to point to individual strings?

Comment: Because `char` is a type that can only contain one element of itself. `char*` is a pointer to some memory location, when you create a string literal(string of characters in quotes) it's actually an array, so you get a pointer back in order that you can perform pointer arithmetic on it to traverse the string.

Comment: Can you explain why this is surprising to you? It's exactly the same situation as `char c = 'h';` versus `char* c = "h";`. (The second example - and yours - shouldn't compile, by the way.)

Comment: I like the questions, that go along the lines of "Why do these 2 different types, are behaving differently?"

Comment: BTW, missing `const` -> `const char* characters[]`.

Comment: @lubgr Not sure it's a dupe, as the OP here seems to be asking about the difference between `char x[]` and `char* x[]`

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist You're right, I retracted the duplicate vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of different types. In your first example you have an array of chars, in your second example you have an array of pointers to chars (array of arrays if you want). [String literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) are of type `const char[]` which translates to `const char*`. You should have a `const` qualifier in your second example:

```
const char* characters[] = {"h","e","l","l","o"};
```

It just so happens your string literals have one character in them followed by a *hidden* null terminating character. So if you had:

```
const char test[] = "h";
```

what you actually have is:

```
const char test[] =  {'h', '\0'};
```

Add a pointer to the above example and you have an array of null terminated character arrays.
To make things more clear you could also have:

```
const char* characters[] = {"hello","world","etc"};
```

Prefer [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to the above approach as it does all the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 3):

> How is the latter able to point to individual strings?

When you write this:

```
char characters[] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
```

you define an array of type `char`, i.e. you have defined a variable of type `char[5]`. Hence you can initialize it with elements of type `char`.

In contrast, when you write:

```
char* characters[] = {"h","e","l","l","o"};
```

you define an array of type `char*`, i.e. you have defined a variable of type `char*[5]` -- and `char*` means pointer to `char`, i.e. *C style string*. Hence you can initialize it with elements of type *string literal*.

Perhaps the second array should more aptly be named `strings[]` instead of `characters[]`.

To be precise, *string literals* such as `'h'`, are themselves of type `const char[2]`<sup>1</sup>, which corresponds in pointer terms to `const char*`. So an array of such strings should be defined `const char* strings[] = ...` and not `char* strings[] = ...`.

---

<sup>1</sup> `const char[2]` and not `const char[1]` as it is null terminated, as in it's an array holding 1st element to be `'h` and 2nd to be `'\0'`